# How to populate a dropdown menu in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, populate

I am trying to populate my dropdown with the value of `testType` but it is not showing up. Is there something I am missing? When I print the data being sent, it is correct but it's not displaying in the actual dropdown menu. I don't want this to be populated everytime - only when the user clicks edit criteria (not for add question).

I'm currently testing it for `criteriaNum = 1` so the dropdown should display `testType = 'Visual Check'`.

This is my EditQuestionnaire.js:

```
export const PureEditQuestionnaire = ({
  criteriaNum,
  criteriaFields,
  image,
  isSaving,
  testType,
  onFieldChange,
  onClickSave,
  getInputValue,
  getDropdownValue,
}) => (
<>
<Header
  tabIndex="-1"
  isAddCriteria={!!criteriaNum}
  onClickSave={onClickSave}
  isSaving={isSaving}
  isOnTop={true}
/>
<CategoryContainer>
  <p>
    Fields with <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span> are required
  </p>

  {criteriaFields.map((field) => (
    <FieldContainer key={field.name}>
      <label htmlFor={field.name.replaceAll(" ", "-")} className="fields">
        {field.name}
      </label>

      {field.type === "input" ? (
        <TextField
          id={field.name.replaceAll(" ", "-")}
          value={getInputValue(field.name)}
          fullWidth={true}
          required={true}
          placeholder={"Enter the " + field.name}
          multiline={field.name === "Description" && true}
          rows={field.name === "Description" ? 4 : 0}
          onChange={(event) =>
            onFieldChange(field.name, event.target.value)
          }
        />
      ) : field.type === "dropdown" ? (
        <>
          {/* <label htmlFor={field.name}>Select the {" " + field.name}</label> */}
          <div id={field.name.replaceAll(" ", "-") + "-desc"}>
            Select the {" " + field.name}
          </div>
          <select
            id={field.name.replaceAll(" ", "-")}
            aria-describedby={field.name.replaceAll(" ", "-") + "-desc"}
            value={field}
            onChange={(event) =>
              onFieldChange(field.name, event.target.value)
            }
          >
            <option selected disabled>
              {/* Select a {" " + field.name} */}
            </option>
            {field.fields.map((field) => (
              <option key={field} value={field}>
                {field}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </>
      ) : (
        <ImageDropbox
          id={field.name.replaceAll(" ", "-")}
          image={image}
          imageFieldName={field.name}
          onImageChange={onFieldChange}
        />
      )}
    </FieldContainer>
  ))}
</CategoryContainer>

<CategoryContainer>
  <h1>Answers</h1>
  <AnswerTable />
</CategoryContainer>
<Header
  onClickSave={onClickSave}
  isSaving={isSaving}
  isOnTop={false}
  isAddCriteria={!!criteriaNum}
/>
</>
)
```

This is the `getDropdownValue` I'm exporting from my `PureEditQuestionnaire`:

```
const getDropdownValue = (fieldName) => {
switch (fieldName) {
  case "Test Type":
    return criteriaValues.testType
  case "Capability":
    return criteriaValues.capability
  default:
    return ""
}
}
```

Comment: Your options look quite odd. I only see the variable field used everywhere and for everything. Consider renaming the local variable passed to the map function to something else like this ```{field.fields.map((optionField) => (``` or if the criteriaFields contains the fields property inside, then it must be ```{criteriaFields.fields.map((innerField) => (```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check you usage of the `select` and `option` element. I'm also not sure what's the object type of `field`.

Hopefully this helps:
[How to use select option in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68014065/how-to-use-select-option-in-react-js)